# How to upload maximum 1gb file in node - nginx

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, adonis.js

I want to increase maximum file size for uploading file on the nginx server in adonis.js project.
I already edit the file 'nginx.conf'. on /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
and set **client_max_body_size 1048576M**
but it returned status code 413(Status Code: 413 Payload Too Large)

Comment: Did you reload your NGINX server after making the change? What is the size of the file you're trying to upload? How are you performing the upload?

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading server by ( nginx -s reload -c <PATH_TO_nginx.conf>) or setting (client_max_body_size 1G;) inside server directive of your config